# What is the correct format in JSON, should I quote names also?

Tags: json

I am writing a JSON file, but I am not sure about which of the following formats is the correct one?

**Quoting variable names and all string values**

```
{
    "class": {
        "number": 2,
        "student": {
            "name": "Tom",
            "age": 1
        },
        "student": {
            "name": "May",
            "age": 2
        }
    }
}
```

or

**Quoting only string values**

```
{
    class: {
        number: 2,
        student: {
            name: "Tom",
            age: 1
        },
        student: 
        {
            name: "May",
            age: 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON Seems like the first one of yours is valid.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first is valid, if you're unaware you can validate your JSON output online pretty easily here: http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: or just try to `JSON.parse` it and see if you get a parse error.

Comment: @MatrixFrog - That won't always fail, depending on browser/implementation, it'll handle some invalid cases as well...what "works" and what's 100% valid often aren't the same thing :)

Answer (score 12):

JSON requires the quotes. See http://json.org for the specifications.

In particular, the *string* production is:

```
string
    '"' characters '"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but the OP's JSON (first construction) may have the proper syntax, but it's going to cause trouble because it repeats the key `student`.

```
import simplejson

data = '''{
    "class": {
        "number": 2,
        "student": {
            "name": "Tom",
            "age": 1
        },
        "student": {
            "name": "May",
            "age": 2
        }
    }
}'''

data_in = simplejson.loads(data)
print(data_in)
```

Yields: `{'class': {'number': 2, 'student': {'age': 2, 'name': 'May'}}}`

Where unique keys `student_1` and `student_2`:

```
import simplejson

data = '''{
    "class": {
        "number": 2,
        "student_1": {
            "name": "Tom",
            "age": 1
        },
        "student_2": {
            "name": "May",
            "age": 2
        }
    }
}'''

data_in = simplejson.loads(data)
print(data_in)
```

Yields: `{'class': {'student_1': {'age': 1, 'name': 'Tom'}, 'number': 2, 'student_2': {'age': 2, 'name': 'May'}}}`

**UPDATE:**
Agree with @Tomas Hesse that an array is better form.  It would look like this:

```
import simplejson

data = '''{
    "class": {
        "number": 2,
        "students" : [
            { "name" : "Tom", "age" : 1 }, 
            { "name" : "May", "age" : 2 }
        ]
    }
}'''

data_in = simplejson.loads(data)
print(data_in)
```

Comment: This answer will suffice but the correct way I believe is to put the students in a array instead.  "students" : [{ "name" : "Tom", "age" : 1},{"name" : "May", "age" : 2}]